# linux yocto kernel driver development easy way

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel, driver, yocto

what is linux yocto based kernel driver development easiest way?

it's known well, the recipe approach involve some headache on how to embed the kernel modified (or some extra/new drivers to debug)  while the rest of the system will be lightweight and easy fit/ easy to boot on the target SoC.

so far a well known solution is to use `devtools modify` command for the kernel recipe (not necessary the `kernel` name but bitbake will assist you on which name to apply instead). it will establish extra `workspace` layer created inside the `build` folder for the kernel already patched to modify and build.

the exact command looks like:

`MACHINE=<this is where your HW specific definition name apply> devtool modify <kernel recipe name>`

but it has some limitations like, after executing `devtool update-recipe`, the patch synthesized will not alter already existing one but add a completely new. so if you have already existing driver patch would like to debug it will not be "refreshed" but another one will be added next to instead.

also by having `devtool`, it's not clear how to append target specific `toolchain` path ahead when it's necessary to modify `.config` by doing `menuconfig` for example.

any alternatives?